# "How to retrieve an url from Firebase Database BEFORE load WebView in Swift?"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, webview, wkwebview

I am building an application with `webView` and Firebase as database. The url that should be used to load the `webView` should come from the database.

I have implemented both `webView` and Firebase correctly but the problem is that my webView is not loading with the url from the database but the url declared in the var declaration.

It seems that viewDidLoad call in priority the methods webView load before the closure inside Database Observe method

If I look at the console, I can clearly see that everything is working BUT the url that should be used to load the `webview` is retrieved from the database AFTER `webview` load...this should be done BEFORE given that I put the retrieve method BEFORE...

```swift
class ViewController:  UIViewController {

    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    var nextUrl = "https://www.google.co.uk/"

    func retrieveUrl () {
        dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("EXAMPLE")

        dbRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let url = value["url"]!
            self.nextUrl = (url as! String)
            print (nextUrl)
        }
        print ("function observe is called")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retrieveUrl()
        print ("webview is about to load")
        let request = URLRequest (url: URL(string: nextUrl)!)
        self.webView.load(request)
        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }
}
```

in the console I can see that "webview is about to load" is printed before nextUrl...which is very strange to me

Comment: In Firebase, database observe method is asynchronous. Therefore; `print (nextUrl)` call after `print ("webview is about to load")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load webView in callback of firebase observer.

Because you are loading webView right after firebase network call its like async work, so webView try to loads with nextUrl is empty or not, to prevent async like behavior you must wait for nextUrl or you should load webView in firebase callback 
Do it like following

```
class ViewController:  UIViewController {
    var dbRef: DatabaseReference!
    var nextUrl = "https://www.google.co.uk/"
    func retrieveUrl () {
        dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("EXAMPLE")
        dbRef.observe(.value) {
            (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let url = value["url"]!
            self.nextUrl = (url as! String)
            print (nextUrl)
            print ("webview is about to load")
            let request = URLRequest (url: URL(string: nextUrl)!)
            self.webView.load(request)
            self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
        }
        print ("function observe is called")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retrieveUrl()
```

Comment: ok many thanks!  I will try. Can you please explain why it should be done so?

Comment: oh yeah sorry ...  because you are loading webView right after firebase network call its like async work, so webView try to loads with nextUrl is empty or not, to prevent async like behavior you must wait for nextUrl or you should load webView in airbase callback

Comment: Ooops, another question: when I change the url in my database into a valid url, nextUrl becomes nil for a curious reason and my app crash...do you have any idea?

Comment: when I change the url in my database into a valid url, nextUrl becomes nil for a curious reason and my app crash...do you have any idea?@Abu Ul Hassan

Comment: i have not gone through this issue, may be your are entering an absolute url instead of a url ...